# Where is the ./configure executable file for Qt 4.7 in Linux if installed via Synaptic?

Tags: linux, qt, configure

I've installed Qt 4.7 on Windows XP before and had to configure it via the configure.exe and a list of settings.

Now I have installed Linux and downloaded Qt 4.7 SDK (and the Qt kitchen sink) via Synaptic.

I have my list of configure flags ready, but I cannot find the ./configure executable to run.

Any ideas where this thing is? Thanks.

By the way, I did see this, but could not find info on the configure executable there:
[Qt.Wiki:Build Qt for Linux](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Build_Qt_For_Linux)

Comment: What about this? http://linuxhelp.blogspot.com/2006/01/creating-and-compiling-qt-projects-on.html

Comment: @Xavier. I looked that linked site over, but didn't see anything about configuring the Qt build. Maybe I missed it. It does give a good overview of how to build a project once your .cpp and etc. are ready.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've installed it from Synaptic, it'll most likely be a binary package - which means it'll have already been configured and built. If you require options that differ from the ones used for that package, you'll probably have to download the source and compile it separately.

Comment: Thanks, Aesin. Any idea where its installed? I'm pretty new to the Linux world. I did try a Find (from Dolphin) in /bin and /usr/share/qt4/, but no such luck.

Comment: Nevermind. I see what you mean now. You're saying that the configure executable doesn't come with the binary package.

Comment: The binary package is just that - a binary package. It has been configured and built and is shipped as-is. No way to change it after the fact.

Comment: Yep - package configure scripts set up headers and files needed for compilation, usually using macros and things defined by the autoconf package to find libraries and appropriate options. Since these parameters are then compiled in, you don't need it and can't use it after that.

Comment: Thanks yall! That explains some things.